# working out fourier transform is C^m

Tags: functional-analysis

I have difficulty working out an exercise. Suppose that a function f satisfies the eastimate $$|f(x)|\leq\frac{C_a}{(1+|x|^N)}$$ for some N>n, n is the dimension of the space. Then $\hat{f}$ is $C^M$ where $1\leq M\leq[N-n]$. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: If everything works as one would hope, what are the derivatives of $\hat{f}$?

Comment: I guess it should be $\int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}(-2\pi ix)f(x)dx$, I just move the deriative inside, or should I use the formula $\partial^{a}\hat{f}(\xi)=((-2\pi i\xi)^a)f)\hat{(\xi)}$?

Comment: The first is correct (for the first derivative). Do you know a theorem when you can differentiate under the integral sign?

Comment: I found it. The reference says both f and the function obtained by moving derivative inside should be integrable. But we have 1+|x| here, why we require N>n?

Comment: For which exponents is $\dfrac{1}{(1 + \lvert x\rvert)^{\alpha}}$ integrable?

Comment: Ha, I see. For x big, we need it to decay fast enough. So the exponent should be bigger than n. Is it correct?

Comment: Right. And how many $x$s can we bring down by differentiating under the integral without losing integrability?

Comment: Ha! It is [N-n]!

Comment: More or less. We need a strict inequality $M < N - n$. So if everything is an integer, we get $C^{N - n - 1}$. If $N$ is not an integer, we get $C^{\lfloor N - n \rfloor}$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! You are so nice!